# Where can I see at what price a company's debt is trading at?

Tags: stocks, bonds, credit, debt

I was reading Barron's today and came across the below quote -

> Hertz’s debt somewhere in the range of 30-40 cents on the dollar. If
>   the stock actually were worth something, the debt ought to fetch
>   something close to par.

I want make sure to avoid companies where the debt is below par and add this as a filter while selecting stocks. Where can one typically find this debt information of companies?

Comment: I just tried looking this up at my broker.  They don’t have any Hertz bonds listed.  Actually they have 1 bond listed but the data for it is invalid.  I’ve tried looking at bonds of other bankrupt companies (like Sears), but they’re not listed.  Probly to protect investors.  Best bet would be to call up your brokerage and just ask if they can find this info for you.

Comment: This data is typically available on Bloomberg terminal and other professional data services. It looks like you can find some of the information you're looking for here: https://markets.businessinsider.com/bonds

Answer (score 1):

Either the quote is wrong or you misunderstood it. Even the debt of healthy companies can be worth less than its par value if interest rates have gone up since the debt was issued, or if there is a dip in the economy that affects the company, but not necessarily severely enough to go bankrupt.

So eliminating companies whose debt is less than par is perhaps too strong a restriction. Certainly debt trading at 40 cents on the dollar is a huge red flag, but I would either choose a lower threshold or use something simpler, like credit ratings, to get a gauge on the risk of default.

To answer the question, there is no (to my knowledge) public website that publishes corporate bond prices since they are not traded by a public exchange like stocks. You'd have to get that information from your broker, who may be connected to other brokers through a (not free) debt quote system.

Comment: The quote is correct. Since HTZ declared bankruptcy, it reflects the expected recovery on the debt. The problem with credit ratings is that they are trailing rather than leading indicators, unlike credit spreads, which respond almost immediately.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD My problem with the quote is that HTX would be trading "close to par" if it were not going bankrupt. Companies can trade at 95% or higher depending on interest rate changes without necessarily being distressed.

Comment: @D Stanley thank you for clarifying. I see what you mean, and I agree. I guess it depends on what we consider "close to par".